# Silicone based polymer that can be functionalised on one end?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

I am looking for a silicone based polymer (think PDMS but I need to do some chemical reactions with it) where I can attach on one side (or both, I am not sure yet) another molecule that has a carboxylic acid at the end or an amine. Maybe some of you know of a PDMS derivative that's functionalised at the end?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That you can buy off the shelve. https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/materials-science/material-science-products.html?TablePage=113790985 And google has 400 000 hits for "end group functionalized PDMS".